# Админ. права при выключенном UAC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, uac

Есть программа, которой нужны админские привилегии (например, доступ в папку "C:\Program Files"). Прога запускается под обычным пользователем.

Если UAC включен - все работает, как полагается выскакивает окошко с запросом повышения привилегий, в манифесте прописано "requireAdministrator".

Если UAC выключен - естественно окошко с запросом привилегий не появляется, и админские права программе недоступны.

Как получить права, если UAC выключен? Я думал если он выключен, то админ.права по-умолчанию доступны.

Answer (score -1):

Правая кнопка по программе - Запуск от имени администратора.